# Polymer 1.0 (app design) - can I "grab" iron-pages?

Tags: polymer-1.0

Unfortunately I don't have a touch screen to experiment live.

I'm using Dart and Polymer 1.0. I'm in [re]design stage of my app, top down.

I have a paper-drawer-panel and its main page has a paper-header-panel, and this contains scrollable paper-tabs. Each tab shows a different "page" (as it seems to the user).

I want users, on their tablets/touch screens, to scroll left and right naturally - in the middle of their screen - to different pages, just as if they had tapped a paper-tab (so they have either option).

Is the best approach to use iron-pages in the paper-header-panel content? (I will also allow them to scroll up and down in the pages, but staying on the same paper-tab of course). Or, more to the point, will it work (grabbing an iron page)?

Thanks

slymp

Answer (score 0):

Iron-pages may not be ideal because it just hide/show the pages. Maybe a better alternative could be use neon-animated-pages with the slide from left/right transitions setup and the track event so you could decide what page to display (next/previous) and let the neon-animated-pages animate the entrance/exit of the elements.